# Bulk API Batch Query

Tags: batch, bulk-api

I have 10 lakhs records in my salesforce contacts. Iam going to use Bulk Api to fetch all these records.How can I write  a SOQL query to fetch records so I can  feed the queries into the batches? And moreover is 10K records is the maximum size of records that a batch can hold?

Comment: eh tell me first what is lakh? =p